# A two-dimensional set of measure zero

Tags: measure-theory

I have a 2D domain $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. This domain contains some set of measure zero $A$, the last understood as the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Is the following true: for almost all $t\in[0,1]$ the set $A_{t}:=\{x\in[0,1]|(t,x)\in A\}$ has measure zero, in standard $\mathbb{R}^{1}$ sense? Actually, I'm hoping to get a negative answer. This question can be more general, for $A$ being $\Omega\times[0,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $\Omega$ being a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.
Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is true. This can, for instance, be seen from Fubini's theorem: Let $\chi_A$ denote the characteristic function of $A$. Then
$$
0 = \int_{[0,1]^2} \chi_A(t,x)dtdx = \int_0^1 \bigg( \int_0^1 \chi_A(t,x)dx \bigg) dt
$$
and hence for almost every $t\in[0,1]$, the function $\int_0^1 \chi_A(t,x)dx$ vanishes, which implies that $A_t$ as defined by you has measure zero.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Always underestimated those characteristic functions, but they seem very useful for such problems. Thanks!

Comment: My advisor calls this itself the Fubini theorem! It  is the heart of that theorem!